# clearInterval() does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js

[enter image description here][1]I have following code

```
function fnIsOnScreen(img, repeats = 5, desc, wait = 2000) {
    let iCounter = 0;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        console.log("Click is running");
        var interval = setInterval(() => {
                client.screenshot().then((data) => {
                    let buf = new Buffer(data.value, 'base64');
                    let img1 = cv.imdecode(buf)
                        result = img1.matchTemplate(img, 5).minMaxLoc();
                    if (result.maxVal >= 0.65) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        console.log("Object found #" + iCounter + " " + desc);
                        resolve(result);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Cant see object yet #" + iCounter);
                        iCounter++;
                        if (iCounter === repeats) {
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            let err = new Error("Object not found : " + desc);
                            throw err;
                            console.log(err);
                            return Promise.reject(err);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .catch ((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
            }, wait);
    }).catch ((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Why am I not able to clear that interval? I call this function few times in a row. It looks like it clears it after the function is called next time but that does not help me much.

https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2018/01/10/kRmO.png

Sorry guys :) I am lil busy here. the if statement works

Comment: What's happening vs what you expect? You haven't made that clear. `clearInterval` *will* stop the timer from repeating, so what is it doing vs what you expect? Are you sure they're being called?

Comment: Maybe your if statements never evaluate to true, or even your `screenshot()` promise never succeeds, then of course your interval will never be cleared.

Comment: Where is `result` declared - or is it missing a declaration?

Comment: *"Sorry guys :) I am lil busy here"* Post questions only when you have the time to stick around and deal with any requests for clarification, etc., that you receive. SO is a very active place, people *will** be looking at your question and trying to help you pretty much as soon as you post. Be respectful of their spending their time to help you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things jump out:

- You never clear the interval in the `catch` on `client.screenshot()`'s promise. Presumably you want to do the same `iCounter` check there that you do in the `else` in `then`.
- You leave the promise you've created via `new Promise` unresolved; returning `return Promise.reject(err);` from the `then` handler on `client.screenshot()`'s promise does nothing to settle the new promise you've created, as you aren't chaining.
- `result` is undeclared in the quoted code.
- I would **strongly** recommend not using `setInterval` to retry an asynchronous operation. It creates a race condition between the operation and the timer.

Here's a solution that attempts retry when the screenshot fails without using a timer at all. Note that I've broken the problem into specific parts: A reusable `timeout` function, a function that attempts the screenshot *once*, and a function that does retries as necessary.

```
function timeout(delay) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
}

function fnIsOnScreenOnce(img, desc, iCounter) {
    return client.screenshot()
        .then((data) => {
            let buf = new Buffer(data.value, 'base64');
            let img1 = cv.imdecode(buf)
            let result = img1.matchTemplate(img, 5).minMaxLoc();
            if (result.maxVal < 0.65) {
                // Fail
                const msg = "Can't see object yet";
                throw new Error(iCounter === undefined ? msg : msg + " #" + iCounter);
            }
            // All good
            return result;
        });
}

function fnIsOnScreen(img, repeats = 5, desc, wait = 2000) {
    let iCounter = 0;
    const attempt = () => fnIsOnScreenOnce(img, desc, iCounter).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
        iCounter++;
        if (iCounter === repeats) {
            // Failed, out of retries
            throw new Error("Object not found : " + desc);
        }
        // Retry after waiting
        return timeout(wait).then(attempt);
    });
    return attempt();
}
```

Live Example with some parts replaced with stubs; it uses some randomness to simulate the screenshot failing or returning `maxVal` above or below the cutoff, so you'll want to run it multiple times to see all the scenarios:

```js
const client = {
    screenshot() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (Math.random () < 0.5) {
                    const maxVal = Math.random();
                    console.log("resolving with " + maxVal);
                    resolve({maxVal});
                } else {
                    console.log("rejecting");
                    reject(new Error("screenshot failed"));
                }
            }, 10);
        });
    }
};

function timeout(delay) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
}

function fnIsOnScreenOnce(img, desc, iCounter) {
    return client.screenshot()
        .then((data) => {
            /*
            let buf = new Buffer(data.value, 'base64');
            let img1 = cv.imdecode(buf)
            let result = img1.matchTemplate(img, 5).minMaxLoc();
            */
            let result = data; // Stand in for the above
            if (result.maxVal < 0.65) {
                // Fail
                const msg = "Can't see object yet";
                throw new Error(iCounter === undefined ? msg : msg + " #" + iCounter);
            }
            // All good
            return result;
        });
}

function fnIsOnScreen(img, repeats = 5, desc, wait = 2000) {
    let iCounter = 0;
    const attempt = () => fnIsOnScreenOnce(img, desc, iCounter).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
        iCounter++;
        if (iCounter === repeats) {
            // Failed, out of retries
            throw new Error("Object not found : " + desc);
        }
        // Retry after waiting
        return timeout(wait).then(attempt);
    });
    return attempt();
}

fnIsOnScreen("img", 5, "desc", 100)
.then(result => { console.log("result", result); })
.catch(err => { console.error("err", err.message); });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: thx for pointing out the mistake :)  I didnt get what you mean by second point I am kinda new to promises

Comment: @trixo: First, apologies -- I made a series of errors adding a non-interval solution. If you're reading this comment, please hit refresh to make sure you see the corrected version.

Comment: @trixo: In your original code, when you give up, you do `return Promise.reject(...)` from a `then` handler on the promise returned by `client.screenshot()`. But that doesn't do anything to reject the promise you created and returned from *your* function. Instead, to reject that promise, you'd call `reject` (the one you got as a parameter, not `Promise.reject`). But again, using an interval for this is not a good idea. :-)

Comment: so if i would like to reject i would just do reject() instead of return promis...

Comment: I do not understand from your code how is it that function is repeating. I see that you used.then and call it again. but wont it work just 2 times and its end afterwards ?

Comment: iCount is not defined :) but otherwise it works very smoothly thx a lot you are smart dude

Comment: @trixo: `iCount` doesn't appear in the answer. :-) And you're right, it's not repeating correctly. I've actually done a **terrible** job on this answer from the get-go. :-) Let's see if I can **finally** fix it. (Since I can't delete it with it being marked "accepted".)

Comment: haha :D Thats funny Yeah I just found out that it does not :) and yeah I have no idea how to fix it :D I can unmark it if you do not have time to fix it

Comment: @trixo: `iCount` didn't but `iCounter` did, in a place where it would cause that error. :-) I've finally fixed the suggsted code (and included a running example). Sorry about that! I don't normally mess things up quite this badly...

Comment: No need to be sorry . You were helping Btw how do i stop execution without throwin error  can i clear variable somehow cause if i wont throw error it continious after 5 rejects   and Thx u for ur help

Comment: @trixo: Why don't you want to throw an error? We catch it, so...

Comment: just to get more knowledge how i can work with this kind of approach :) Is there other way than throw err to stop it ? :) i set variable to let and overwrote it but that does not work :)

Comment: @trixo: You could `return Promise.reject()` which would have the same effect (rejecting the promise).

Comment: Loading Finished
Login test running
Can't see object yet #0->Email button
Can't see object yet #1->Email button
Can't see object yet #2->Email button
Can't see object yet #3->Email button
Can't see object yet #4->Email button
Object not found : Email button
Test Failed  Thx so much works very well :)

Answer (score 0):

create an `array` to save intervals and clear it one by one.the `intervalArray` gets all intervals and clear it ones.

```
  function fnIsOnScreen(img, repeats = 5, desc, wait = 2000) {
    let iCounter = 0;
    let intervalArray = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        console.log("Click is running");
        var interval = setInterval(() => {
                client.screenshot().then((data) => {
                    let buf = new Buffer(data.value, 'base64');
                    let img1 = cv.imdecode(buf)
                        result = img1.matchTemplate(img, 5).minMaxLoc();
                    if (result.maxVal >= 0.65) {

                        intervalArray.push(interval)
                        clearintro(intervalArray);
                        console.log("Object found #" + iCounter + " " + desc);
                        resolve(result);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Cant see object yet #" + iCounter);
                        iCounter++;
                        if (iCounter === repeats) {
                            intervalArray.push(interval)
                            clearintro(intervalArray)
                            let err = new Error("Object not found : " + desc);
                            throw err;
                            console.log(err);
                            return Promise.reject(err);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .catch ((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
            }, wait);
    }).catch ((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

function clearintro(intervalArr) {
    intervalArr.map(item => {
        clearInterval(item);
    })

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not able to clear interval because you have defined interval variable inside of function make it globally then you will be able to clear it outside and inside anywhere of function

```
  var interval  ="";
   function fnIsOnScreen(img, repeats = 5, desc, wait = 2000) {
   let iCounter = 0;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    console.log("Click is running");
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        client.screenshot().then((data) => {
                let buf = new Buffer(data.value, 'base64');
                let img1 = cv.imdecode(buf)
                result = img1.matchTemplate(img, 5).minMaxLoc();
                if (result.maxVal >= 0.65) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    console.log("Object found #" + iCounter + " " + desc);
                    resolve(result);
                } else {
                    console.log("Cant see object yet #" + iCounter);
                    iCounter++;
                    if (iCounter === repeats) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        let err = new Error("Object not found : " + desc);
                        throw err;
                        console.log(err);
                        return Promise.reject(err);
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }, wait);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})

}
```

clear interval outside of function

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: No, that isn't remotely correct. The places using `interval` close over it just fine, making it a global is neither necessary nor a good idea.

Comment: Overall solution will definitely work if your conditions are properly working as true and false .please check your conditions by breaking code into steps and check the logs